# How to prepare for Technical Lead Engineer position?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, software-development, tech-industry, teamleader

The parameters of the role: I know this will be a team of ten devs and it's an ongoing project which is partially documented and I am replacing the guy that left, tech stack is predominantly .NET microservices I directly report to PM and there is a non-technical BA on the team and me and two offshore teams of devs.

**In which areas would be most prudent to invest my time preparing? Which are the biggest challenges (surprises) when making this switch? Lacking which skills would get me sacked on the spot during trial?**

Comment: This is a little to vague to be answerable-  the definiton of a position like this varies so much from place to place that I have no idea what you'll be doing.  I've been a tech lead and it basically meant architect, I've been a tech lead and it meant hands on programming with some project management duties, and I've been a lead and it meant I was their manager in all but name.  With that spread, its hard to guide you.

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi Gabe, thanks for the comment, I see what you mean, In which way I should be more specific to make it easier to answer the question? Should I describe the company in more detail? Or myself and my experience?

Comment: Tell us what the parameters of the role are?  Are you expected to actively code, or are you expected to spend most of your time on other things?  And honestly some of that will be set on the job by the interactions between you and your manager and how you work together.  In general, studying conflict resolution and brushing up on architecture aren't bad ideas, but what the highest bang for your buck is is hard to guess.

Comment: @GabeSechan updated the question, it would be great if you could give more advice on how could I further improve the question.

Comment: Note that leading well is as much about listening as anything else. Try to make sure folks are comfortable talking to you, and to each other, about ideas and needs and challenges. Try to get consensus on the direction the team is going and why. Learn the art of "great idea but not tip priority right now; log it in Jira (or whatever you're using) and we'll come back to it when time permits. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your answers-  that you'll be working with 2 offshore teams with a PM involved already-  I'd say that your keys to success will be working with those offshore teams and getting what you need out of them.  It looks like you're set up to be part architect, part overseeing engineer.  As such, communicating clearly and efficiently with non-english speakers and the ability to describe what you want may be the most important things to work on.  Next would come the ability to give good code reviews and architectural reviews as work comes in from them-  you need to make sure the quality of their work stands up, and that they aren't missing things in the bigger picture (offshore teams are notorious for doing only exactly what they're told, especially if outsourced).  My guess is you'll do less hands on work yourself.  The organization is set up sort of like an expediter in a restaurant-  you assign work, and ensure its up to quality.

At least that's my read based off the description of the org.

Answer (score 3):

Contact your PM and ask him for a list of your job responsibilities and expectations from you. You can mention that it is to prepare for your role before you join, and even ask for suggestions.

(But do not tell your PM, or anyone at your company, that you feel over your head or unqualified for the job.)

They know you are qualified or they wouldn't have hired you. (Even if you are "unqualified", and they hired you out of desperation, that's still works in your favour, right? :).  Rather, they believe that you have the potential to do your role satisfactorily. Everybody experiences anxiety at a new role in a new company. Don't overthink, and work yourself up about it.

Answer (score 2):

Work on your communication and leadership.

It's harder to guess which skills you need to practice, and inefficient to practice them out of place. It's easy to see you'll need to lead and communicate effectively. Pick book(s) or classes on empathetic communication, technical communication and leadership. You should ask your team-to-be for recommendations. I like *How To Win Friends and Influence People* by Dale Carnegie, the standard bearer.

If you don't like that idea, then perhaps you could reach out to the PM, the guy that left, or ask for the partial documentation.

Comment: `How To Win Friends and Influence People` is a classic :) read it in my twenties, Thanks.